# Verifying response for AJAX calls in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filter, interceptor

I how a lot of controllers that can return **null** as result.

My goal is to verify it for correctness and **throw appropriate exception**.

Will be good to know your thoughts:

1. How it can be achived using **spring stuff**(Is already exist any
   filter to filter ajax call in sping mvc)?
2. Will be it corect to create some **servlet filter or interceptor** in this case?
3. Another way how it can be achived.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well... write spring mvc tests?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested - use spring MVC test framework. With it you can nicely test the results of your ajax requests.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-test-server

There is a quite nice example:

```
   @Test
    public void getAccount() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/accounts/1").accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("Lee"));
    }
```

but check the page for necessary setup.